# Big Sur Update wiped my /etc/apache2/extra

Tags: software-update, apache, big-sur

I think the title is self explanatory, but to say it again, I updated to MacOS 11 and all my extra configs of Apache decided to go bye-bye.

To add insult to injury, there appeared a bunch of *.conf~previous files, who are also the default settings and not mine...

While it is just a  setback, and I can redo everything, does anyone have any idea of where and if I could find the old ones?

Edit: After finishing and recovering everything, only then did I realize that macOS kept all my changes neatly in the Relocated Items on my Desktop. For anyone looking into this in the future, be sure to check if it is there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently modified .conf files are reset to their original state not just during the initial upgrade to Big Sur but also during minor updates.

Your modified .conf files are placed in "Previously Relocated Items n" subdirectories in /User/Shared.

This is the last line of the httpd.conf file:

Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf

To keep your modified .conf files from being overwritten after each update you could put them in the "other" directory.  If you have more than one .conf file and there are order dependencies then put those .conf files in a subdirectory of "other" and include them from a .conf file in "other".

Comment: The /other solution is amazing! You would still need to edit the main conf file though... PS: welcome Ted!

Comment: I was hoping that "other" would obviate the need to edit the main .conf file.  What edits might be required?  Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: You are right! It doesn't! My bad...

Answer (score 6):

Just restore them from the backup you made before starting the upgrade. That's way quicker then searching for them on the upgraded system.

On APFS based systems, remember, your custom files and data are on the “data” filesystem and not on the system itself.

Also, look for a relocated items folder on your desktop in case Apple intentionally set aside your modifications.