# Big Sur Updates Reset Apache Files

Tags: apache

Concerning these Apache files:

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/vhosts/httpd-vhosts.conf

Unlike the previous version of MacOS, each Big Sur update resets these Apache .conf files to their original state, wiping out my changes.  These are the only files I changed, so I assume that if I had changed any others that the update would have reset those also.

At the bottom of the original httpd.conf file is this line:

Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf

Any .conf files that I place in this directory are left alone during an update.  Should I leave the original httpd.conf file alone and in its original state and place all the changes I need to make in .conf files in the /private/etc/apache2/other subdirectory?  I think this would work but it seems strange because, for example, there's the line "ServerAdmin you@example.com" in the original which feels like it should be edited to be my own admin email address, but if I instead create .../other/*.conf files then I'll be setting "ServerAdmin" again, which feels very klugey but which I hope works and is kosher.

Is this the right way to do things?  Or is there a better way?

(I know that my versions of the files get placed in "Previously Relocated Items n" subdirectories in /Users/Shared, but I'd prefer not to have to perform manual restorations after each update.)

(There was a very similar question several months ago at [Big Sur Update wiped my /etc/apache2/extra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406297/big-sur-update-wiped-my-etc-apache2-extra?newreg=03c6f265e0544a709e66242c47683a7e), and I would have preferred posting this to that thread, but the tips say not to post requests for help or clarification, which seems odd, but I'll follow the guidelines.)

Comment: The answer I gave there was based on the assumption that only the initial upgrade to Big Sur removed user-changed Config files. As we now known it happens for minor updates as well so using other/my.conf sounds reasonable. You might just post this as an answer on the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Apache is not the only service whose configuration files get overwritten with every update. My annoyance is the SNMP daemon.

For Apache, I suggest that you stop using the Apple distributed Apache. Replace it with the Homebrew version.

The Homebrew version uses `/usr/local/etc/httpd/` for configuration, `/usr/local/var/www` for document root and is completely independent of Apple's version and so will not get modified by macOS updates.

Just in case you are not familiar with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).  You will find numerous web postings about how to install and configure Apache under Homebrew - an [example](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/). And you are already aware that there have been other Apache questions in Ask Different.